# How to share Realm (using swift) in extensions and AppDelegates

Tags: swift, realm, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am having some problems with `RealmSwift` with the `Notification Service Extension`. I hope everyone can help me or give me some advice. I sincerely thank you all! And my English is not good, let me know if there is something unclear.

First, I used FCM to push the message to my `ios` device, I need to save my push notification to the `ios` device (using `Realm`).
There are only two cases that have a way to save successfully.

1.app running

2.app is killed/background, and click to push banner notifications I hope I can do the app off/background and save it without having to click on the banner notification.

So I used the following method

1.Add `Notification Service Extension` in the project

2.Enable Background fetch/Remote notifications

3.Project and `Notification Service Extension` added to app groups
I know that Extension can't share data, so I changed the default path of `Realm`.

I added the following code to `AppDelegates.swift` and added the same code in `NotificationService.swift`.
like this

```
 let sharedDirectory: URL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.myapp")! as URL
        let sharedRealmURL = sharedDirectory.appendingPathComponent("db.realm")
        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: sharedRealmURL)
```

After I added these codes, when the app is killed or the background, the push message can be successfully saved to Realm, but not every time, 10 push notifications will only store 5, and most Importantly, the functionality that could have been stored in the app runing or clicking on the banner notification failed. 
(But it is stored, because if I cancel the code that changes the default path of Realm, the data that has not been saved will be displayed again)

My Realm class

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

 class Order: Object {

    @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var amount = ""
    @objc dynamic var createDate = Date()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class RealmDao: NSObject {

    static let shared = RealmDao()
    private var realm: Realm!

    private override init() {

        self.realm = try! Realm()
    }

    func getRealmObject() -> Realm {
        return self.realm
    }
}
```

Part of my AppDelegate.swift

```
    let realm =  try! Realm()
    let order: Order = Order()
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        ////share Realm
        let sharedDirectory: URL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.myapp")! as URL
        let sharedRealmURL = sharedDirectory.appendingPathComponent("db.realm")
        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: sharedRealmURL)
tainerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.myapp")

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            Messaging.messaging().delegate = self // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge], completionHandler: { granted, error in
                if granted {
                    print("ok...")
                } else {
                    print("no...")
                }
            })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        return true
    }
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {  
        let sharedDirectory: URL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.myapp")! as URL
        let sharedRealmURL = sharedDirectory.appendingPathComponent("db.realm")
        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: sharedRealmURL)
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo 
        print("userInfo: \(userInfo)")
        guard
        let aps = userInfo[AnyHashable("aps")] as? NSDictionary,
        let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary,
        let body = alert["body"] as? String,
        let title = alert["title"] as? String
        else {
            // handle any error here
            return
        }
        print("Title: \(title) \nBody:\(body)")
        order.name = title
        order.amount = body
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(order)
        }
        completionHandler([.badge, .sound, .alert])
    }
```

All my NotificationService.swift

```
import UserNotifications
import Firebase
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import Realm

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    let realm = try! Realm()
    let order: Order = Order()

    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {


        let sharedDirectory: URL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.myapp")! as URL
        let sharedRealmURL = sharedDirectory.appendingPathComponent("db.realm")
        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: sharedRealmURL)


        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        let message = request.content.userInfo
        print("userInfo: \(message)")
        guard
            let aps = message[AnyHashable("aps")] as? NSDictionary,
            let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary,
            let title = alert["body"] as? String,
            let body = alert["title"] as? String
            else {
                // handle any error here
                return
        }
        print("Title: \(title) \nBody:\(body)")

        order.name = title
        order.amount = body

        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(order)
        } 
        if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {

            // Modify the notification content here...
            bestAttemptContent.body = "\(bestAttemptContent.body) [fortest]"

            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)


        }
    }

}
```

I think my problem seems to be a problem with the default path change, because when I change the path, the push notification in the execution is saved, but the code that must delete the change path will be displayed! Is it what I missed that causes the original path to still exist (so the push notification in the app running will be stored in another data table?)

Comment: It's a little unclear what is actually failing. If you send 10 notifications to the app, does it actually receive all 10 whether it's running or in the background? Also, are you expecting an app that is not running (i.e. killed) to respond to a notification?

Comment: The push notification of the killed app has a new path (the current viewtable displays the data table of the new path)
The app push notification in progress is also stored, but saved to the old path (so it is not displayed in the current view)
After changing the path back (viewtable shows the original path of the data table), the data that has just not been displayed is displayed.
This means that both push notifications are stored, but not in the same database, I don't know why this happens because I have changed the path.

Comment: I hope that the push notifications can be stored regardless of the circumstances of the app.

Comment: Send 10 notifications, 10 are received, I mean, when the app is in the background or killed, he does not necessarily trigger the program to execute when it is in the background or killed.